# how to dump signals inside a task or function

Tags: system-verilog

I tried to use `debug_access=all` in vcs command line, but it seems I still can't dump the signals declared inside the `task()`. Is there any args I need to use?

Comment: Should be `+` (not `=`) i.e. debug_access+all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, tools do not yet allow you to dump variables with automatic lifetimes. This is because they come in and out of existence. Also, because of re-entrant behavior from threads or recursion, there might be multiple instances of the same named variable.

If these signals are inside a class method, you might be able to move them outside  and make them class members. Otherwise you should be able to declare them as static variables as long as there is no re-entrant behavior.

Comment: Thanks Dave. I'll try to do that

Answer (score 0):

dave_59 is correct, there's no way to do this.  For tasks at least you can drive signals that are declared elsewhere inside the task.  And you'll be able to monitor those signals.  Functions I don't believe this is possible to modify external signals from inside a function.  All inputs/outputs must be declared for a function.

Comment: Thanks Russell for your explanation

Comment: The statement about functions is not correct. This is exactly why `always_comb` blocks look into the contents of a function to determine sensitivity.